# Grafana: how to filter queries within one panel?

Tags: variables, grafana

I want to write 3 different queries within one panel. All the queries gonna return the similar structure of data: timeseries, several linegraphs in time.

I need Grafana to draw a visualization of just one of the queries depending on the option chosen in filter variable.

How can I do that?

The version is 8.4.3

I created a variable with custom names of options and tried to mention them within each query via $queryoption = 'Query A'.
Also tried to use 'Repeat options' on the right side in edit mode of panel.
But no luck yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by embedding variable in your queries, and returning results only if variable's value is corresponding to correct query.

For example, create variable `queryoption` with values `A`, `B` and `C`.

And add expressions into your queries that will be true only if according value of variable is selected.

###### Query A

```
select * from table1
where 
 -- your existing where clause
 and '$queryoption' = 'A'
```

###### Query A

```
select * from table2
where 
 -- your existing where clause
 and '$queryoption' = 'B'
```